# Laravel : How to add a confirmation on delete button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

I have the following code:

```
{{ Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','url'=>['/back/roles/delete/'.$row->id],'style'=>'display:inline' ]) }} 
{{ Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger' ]) }} 
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I want to add confirmation on this delete button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This use `onsubmit`

```
'onsubmit' => 'return confirmDelete()'
```

**Write like this**

```
{{ Form::open([
    'method'   => 'DELETE',
    'url'      => ['/back/roles/delete/' . $row->id],
    'style'    => 'display:inline', 
    'onsubmit' => 'return confirmDelete()' 
]) }}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function confirmDelete(){

     var conform = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
     if (conform)
       return true;
     else
       return false;
     }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"

Comment: Why are you adding jquery ?

Comment: added jquery for change <select> style that i have used

Comment: Thank you a lot dear @VikasKatariya i really appreciate your helping

Answer (score 2):

Call event `onsubmit` before submit the form.

```
{{ Form::open(['method'=>'DELETE','url'=>['/back/roles/delete/'.$row->id],'style'=>'display:inline','onsubmit' => 'return deleteconform()' ]) }} 
    {{ Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger' ]) }} 
    {{ Form::close() }}


<script>

  function deleteconform()
  {
  var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
  if (x)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: it says "  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\news\resources\views\admin\role\list.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' (0) "

Comment: have you put it after style tag??  `,'onsubmit' => 'return deleteconform()'`

Comment: copy the whole form and replace it with your code. And use this script below of your code.